# Is it possible to replace color code on using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

I want to help how to replace color code on using jquery..

**For example :** `div` has  `#F8699B` to replace instead of `#C04848`

pls give any idea...

Thanks,

Comment: which element you want to change the code.

Comment: You want to change all elements with same colour? This will make you content invisible.... GREAT TRICK! XDDDD

Comment: Do you mean text color?

Comment: @PushkerYadav : `div ` element

Comment: @balaG : yeah .. i want to change background color also..

Comment: If you want to change background color of DIV then change it by using id like `$('#testId').css('background-color','#C04848');` or if you want change all DIVs the use `$('div').css('background-color','#C04848')`.

Answer (score 0):

is this your expectation..

```js
$('#change').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('div').css('background-color','#C04848')
 });
```

```css
div{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#F8699B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> </div>
<button id="change"> change </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery's `css` method can set any css style attribute. It's used like this:

```
$('jQuery selector').css({"css property name":"css property value"});
```

To changing background color on a div with `id="test"`

```
$('#test').css('background-color','#FF0000');
```